# There exists a permutation $(A_1, \ldots , A_n)$ of the vertices $V =\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n−1\}$, $(A_i,A_{i+1})\in E$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph on $n$ vertices, $V = \{1, \ldots,n\}$, such that for every pair of distinct vertices $i, j \in V$, exactly one of the two possible directed edges $(i, j)$ or $(j, i)$ is in the edge set $E$ (but not both). Prove that there must exist a permutation $(A_1, \ldots, A_n)$ of the vertices $V =\{1, \ldots,n\}$,such that for all $i\in \{1, \ldots,n−1\}, (A_i,A_{i+1})\in E$.

I can think of how it is true but got stuck on proving it. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? If you show your thought process so far, we can better help you.

Comment: Start with a base case where you have 2 vertices, show that it works, use induction over the number of vertices.

Comment: Furthermore, there is a unique permutation $(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n)$ such that $(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n)$ forms a directed path in $G$ iff $G$ has no directed cycles (i.e., a closed path $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_l,v_1)$, where each $v_{i}v_{i+1}$ is an arc in $G$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,l-1$, and $v_lv_1$ is also an arc in $G$).  Equivalently, there exists a permutation $(A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n)$ of vertices such that the in-degree of $A_i$ is $i-1$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$.  Equivalently, the relation  $\to$ on $V$ defined by $$u\to v$$ iff there is a directed path in $G$ from $u$ to $v$ is an order relation on $V$.

Comment: @ClairGoodman You have not accepted the answer. May I ask what is the reason? If you do not understand the answer, please comment. If you want the author to improve the answer, please comment. It is the convention and protocol for the asker to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show it by induction on the number of vertices in the graph $G$.

Base case: when there is only two vertices, the claim is true.
Assume now that for graph with $n$ vertices, the claim is true, we have to show that a graph on $n+1$ vertices, the claim is true.

So let $G$ be a graph on $n+1$ vertices $\{v_1,...,v_{n+1}$}. let's look at the vertex $v_{n+1}$,

Case 1:suppose it is adjacent only to outgoing edges.  Then by induction hypothesis, the graph induced by vertices $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ has a directed path, says, $v_1,...,v_n$. Well now, $v_{n+1},v_1,...,v_n$ is a directed path in $G$.

Case2: Suppose $v_{n+1}$ is adjacent to only ingoing edges, then by induction hypothesis, the graph induced by vertices $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ has a directed path, says, $v_1,...,v_n$. Well now, $v_1,...,v_n,v_{n+1}$ is a directed path in $G$.

Case3: Suppose it is not case 1 nor case 2, then again by induction hypothesis, the graph induced by vertices $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ has a directed path, says, $v_1,...,v_n$. Suppose we have edge $(v_1,v_{n+1})$ and for all $i$, we have edges $(v_iv_{n+1})$ and $(v_{i+1}v_{n+1})$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$, we are back to case 2. So there must be $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ such that $(v_i,v_{n+1})$ and $(v_{n+1},v_{i+1})$ are edges in the graph. Well, $v_1,...,v_i,v_{n+1},v_{i+1},...,v_n$ is a hamiltonian directed path! done